# Do I need "cmd /c"?

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I've seen two different ways of calling `icacls` from VBScript:

```
oShell.Exec("icacls ...
```

or

```
oShell.Exec("%COMSPEC% /c Echo Y| icacls ...
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you don't need to run it in a Command Prompt if it's an external command (executable, script, etc.). So if you can go to *Start → Run…* and run it from there, then you can run your application directly with all arguments, etc.

However, if you're using CMD builtin features, like [internal commands](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) (`dir`, `echo`, `mklink`, …), the pipe (`|`), or I/O redirection (`>`, `>>`, `<`), you *must* run the commandline in CMD, because otherwise these features wouldn't be available. The parameter `/c` is just to tell CMD to terminate after the command completes. It's not required, but it's good practice to put it there, so you can easily replace it with `/k` (keep CMD open after the command completes) for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for the `/C` switch using `CMD /?`.

The `/C` switch tells the `cmd.exe` program to return after it runs the specified command line. If it does not return, you will be left in a `cmd` shell. I do not know what this would look like from VBS.

My guess would be that, yes, you need `/C`.